# Filter an IP address

Tags: php, jinput, filter

I've written the following to get the user IP:

```
private function getIpAddress()
{
    $server = JFactory::getApplication()->input->server;

    if (!empty($server->get('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')))
    {
        $ip = $server->get('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    }
    else if (!empty($server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')))
    {
        $ip = $server->get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

I'd like to filter the value using the [JFilterInput->clean()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php#L138) approach, using one of the options available, such as `'STRING'`, `'INT'`, etc.

I looked at `INT`, but don't think this will allow IP's with the following regex:

```
$pattern = '/[-+]?[0-9]+/';
```

as it doesn't accept a `.`(dot).

---

I then looked at `CMD`, and was wondering if this would be the best one to use as I believe it does allow a `.`(dot):

```
$pattern = '/[^A-Z0-9_\.-]/i';
```

---

Would it be best to use `CMD`? If not, which one? Or would be be best to use one of the native PHP filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, I've used PHP native `filter_var` with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP` filter, like so:

```
return filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

I'm still of course open to other suggestions

Comment: I reckon you're using the best approach with this, please award yourself the green tick.  You only need to include flags or supplemental regex if you want to further tighten the filter [How do I check if a users input is a valid IP address or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6211148/2943403) & [regex](https://regex101.com/r/o10tFv/1)